# How to obtain the Shimmering armor transmog set

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I'm interested in getting a set of this gear for transmog:

http://www.wowhead.com/transmog-set=16

It's tough to tell from comments alone what the easiest way to farm all pieces for this transmog set are.

Would anyone be able to offer a solution for the fastest way to obtain them all?

Answer (score 2):

Picking up specific green-quality items is extremely difficult. While green items in general are common, there are many different types, so you will have a tough time farming any particular piece. Also, since many low level players are actually alts, many of them don't see much value in putting these items on the Auction House.

If you cannot find similar items in blue- or purple-quality* (eg. you can easily farm [Acidic Walkers](http://www.wowhead.com/item=9454) instead of [Shimmering Boots](http://www.wowhead.com/item=6562)), I'd recommend both farming and searching the Auction House. You can search the Auction House efficiently by using shopping lists included in auctioning addons such as [Auctioneer](http://auctioneeraddon.com/dl/) or [Auctionator](http://www.curse.com/addons/wow/auctionator).

As for farming, you'll want to keep a few things in mind:

1. The drop rate for a specific green-quality item is extremely low, commonly less than 1%.
2. Rare and rare-elite enemies are guaranteed to drop at least one item of green-quality or better as of the Cataclysm expansion (at least from my personal experience).
3. Chests are worth exploring if you plan to farm dungeons and have the means to open the chests. When I was farming Scarlet Monastery for transmog greens, I kept a stack of Engineer explosives to open chests and found two pieces in chests.

In terms of what you should kill, I recommend doing your best to farm for as many pieces at once that you can. Each of them has a level range of mobs that they drop from:

```
Wrist: 16 ~ 22
Hands: 17 ~ 23
Belt:  18 ~ 24
Legs:  21 ~ 26
Chest: 22 ~ 27
```

So, the sweet spot for farming these items is by killing mobs that are level 22, broadening as you find items from either extreme of the level ranges. All of the items show that they have been dropped from mobs at level 22 in **Duskwood**, **Hillsbrad Foothills**, and **Wetlands**. I recommend that you set your Hearthstone in one of these zones and dedicate an hour or so each day to farming kills (and checking the Auction House) until you get your items, as I did.

* *If you are interested in searching for compatible/acceptable blue- or purple-quality items to farm instead of green-quality items, the [MogIt](http://www.curse.com/addons/wow/mogit) addon may come in handy.*

Answer (score 0):

You can go get the [Acidic Walkers](http://www.wowhead.com/item=9454) from the Gnomeregan boss "Viscous Fallout".

Other than that one, these are all low 20's random drops.  Your options are:

1. Camp the Auction House and hope one gets listed (not likely, these items aren't so great so people don't know there's any demand).
2. Go to zones where they drop (such as wetlands, arathi highlands, northern stranglethorn) and offer to buy in general.
3. Go to zones where they drop and farm them yourself.